# Report Portal - How to avoid unwanted logs in console?

Tags: python, robotframework, reportportal

I get the below messages for every test step, which is bit annoying. I need to process the console logs in a different way.

```
  
send: b'PUT /api/v2/superadmin_personal/item/14278b98-4430-4d2e-8301-1e30501da3b3 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: abc.lab.com:8080\r\nUser-Agent: python-requests/2.27.1\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nAccept: */*\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nAuthorization: Bearer 2c0717a7-b477-4e02-b1b5-df2a2757db70\r\nContent-Length: 137\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n'
send: b'{"endTime": "1646987482101", "status": "PASSED", "issue": null, "launchUuid": "f380b026-d7c9-4596-b80a-dcaec6fa82f2", "attributes": null}'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
header: Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
header: Content-Type: application/json
header: Date: Fri, 11 Mar 2022 08:30:58 GMT
header: Expires: 0
header: Pragma: no-cache
header: X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
header: X-Frame-Options: DENY
header: X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
header: Content-Length: 93
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `rp.http.logging=false` in the `reportportal.prop` file or as a JVM parameter.

Answer (score 0):

There is a common switch for all HTTP requests/responses Python sends:

```py
from http.client import HTTPConnection

HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 0
```

Unfortunately Python uses just `print` to log HTTP ([as here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/http/client.py#L979)), ignoring his [own logging framework](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/main/Lib/logging). That's really silly, but here where Python is. Therefore there is no any straight way to configure what you want log and what you would like to skip. You can just turn on or off console printing for all HTTP requests.